# Karaf switch to another version bundle

Tags: servlets, war, karaf

I've got two versions (1.0 and 2.0) in karaf of the same war bundle containing the servlet running on the same address. I'm running it with this command:

> bundle:install -s
>   "webbundle:file:///home/marat/projects/webmodule/target/webmodule-1.0.war?Bundle-SymbolicName=Runner&Web-ContextPath=/sample"

And both war bundles are shown Active in Karaf webconsole.

I have an app that pings the address http://localhost:8181/sample/hello (the servlet)  every 10ms (the app sends GET requests). Firstly the app is getting the answers from the servlet represented by war v1.0. If I stop the bundle containing war v1.0 I expect that karaf automatically switches the requests sent to address http://localhost:8181/sample/hello to war v2.0 since the servlet in that bundle is on the same address as of war 1.0. The app gets this response instead:

> java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL:
>   http://localhost:8181/sample/hello

When I restart a pinger app then it successfully connects to war v2.0.

What can I do to make Karaf switch without automatically to war v2.0 when I stop war version 1.0?

Answer (score 0):

I think the second war is not deployed, you can't register the same endpoint twice.

Comment: It seems to be deployed, I can see it it active in webconsole. And when I stop the first one I can connect to it with my http-client.